# Не создается файл для записи данных в него

Tags: python, datetime

Есть скрипт, которые собирает с коммутаторов определенные данные и выводит их в файл в csv формате.
Задача передо мной стоит такая: при выполнении скрипта нужно, чтобы файл создавался c названием=текущей дате и времени, в в него все записывалось. Но по какой-то неведомой для меня причине возникает ошибка. Текст ее ниже.

Если меняю имя файла, например, на test.txt, то все работает. test.txt создается автоматом и в нем все нужные мне данные.

```
    tz_Moscow = pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow')
    datetime_Moscow = datetime.now(tz_Moscow)
    filename = datetime_Moscow.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

    int_descriptions_dict = get_interface_descriptions(device)
    output = send_command(device, command)
    match = regex.finditer(output)
    data = [['interface', 'description', 'mac-address']]
    for row in match:
        data.append([row.group('intf'), int_descriptions_dict.get(row.group('intf')), row.group('mac')])
    with open(f'mac-add-{filename}.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for row in data:
            writer.writerow(row)
    


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vsfomin/python-scripts/mac-address-collector.py", line 170, in <module>
    with open(f'mac-add-{filename}.csv', 'w') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mac-add-13/01/2022.csv'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все просто, слэши в названии файла думаются для `python` как полный путь к файлу. Следуя вашей ошибке, то имя файла будет `2022.csv` и файл будет лежать в директории `mac-add-13/01/`. Поскольку у вас такой директории не существует, вы и получаете данную ошибку

измените здесь

```py
filename = datetime_Moscow.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

Все должно заработать и заиграть новыми красками

Назавания файлов не могут содержать в себе слэши и еще ряд специальных символов

Comment: Точно! Спасибо.

Comment: ничего страшного, на здоровье=)